# javascript - pass string (with spaces - from json) to function

Tags: json, string, space

how's it going..

I'm trying to pass a string result from json, to a function when click a button but i have some issues.

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function) {
...
   $.getJSON(url, {data...}, function result() {
       var data = eval(result);

       for (var i in data) {
          $("body").append("<button onclick='ShowMore("+data[i].AREA+")'>"+data[i].AREA+</button>");
       }

   });

});

function ShowMore(area){
   alert(area);
}
```

Explanation:

I have on my table some company areas (**SYSTEM, MARKETING, HUMAN SOURCES, etc. - many areas with 'space' on the name**).

Then i have another table (EMPLOYESS) that belong each area.

But i need to pass the 'AREAs NAME' to the function ShowMore(variable) to do a list with all the members of that area (i don't know if i'm explainin very well).

When i click the button, i don't have any alert.. but, when i change the **onclick=''** function ... (for example **onclick="+data[i].CODAREA+"**) the result alerts good (**11,14,19,20..**) ...

Is there any problema with the space on the AREAs NAME.

Thank you for answers, Greetings

Comment: you need put the `\'` to string, the CODAREA works because number don't need `\'` to works. try `'ShowMore(\'"+data[i].AREA+"\')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("body").append("<button onclick='alert(\""+data[i].AREA+"\")'>"+data[i].AREA+"</button>");
```

You have a typo in the `data[i].AREA+</button>");`
should be `data[i].AREA+"</button>");`

also escape the "" so that data[i].AREA will be read as string

Answer (score 0):

about your code, you can scape like below...

```
$(document).ready(function) {
...
   $.getJSON(url, {data...}, function result() {
       var data = JSON.parse(result);
       var btn = "";

       for (var i in data) {

          btn = "<button ";
          btn += "onclick='ShowMore(\'";
          btn += data[i].AREA;
          btn += "\')'>";
          btn += data[i].AREA;
          btn += "</button>";

          $("body").append(btn);
       }

   });

});

function ShowMore(area){
   alert(area);
}
```

but you can do it with a faster method...

```
$(document).ready(function) {
...
   $.getJSON(url, {data...}, function result() {
       var data = JSON.parse(result);
       var btn;

       for (var i in data) {

         btn = document.createElement("button");
         btn.innerText = data[i].AREA;

         document.body.appendChild( btn );

         btn.addEventListener( "click", function(){

              ShowMore( data[i].AREA);

         }, true);
       }

   });

});

function ShowMore(area){
   alert(area);
}
```

if data is a array, i think is better use `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`